# pip install watson-nlp proplem

Tags: ubuntu, pip, nlp, ibm-watson

When I try to install `watson-nlp` to complete my projects on Ubuntu, I get the following error:

```
abdo@abdo:~$ pip install watson-nlp
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

I tried to install using pipx but the same error was produced. Installing `watson-nlp` on Windows 10 and Fedora 38 in the past had no issues, but I need to use Ubuntu as there are programs that aren't available on other operating systems.

Comment: are you using virtual env?